# Using system() to run a "cat" command in perl creates the required file but it is blank

Tags: perl

I want to run two shell commands through my Perl script which creates the `find.txt` file with my pattern search. Following is the shell script which runs fine and gives the result when run from the shell:

```
cat "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/ns.conf" | grep "add\|set\|enable" | awk '{print $2}' > find.txt
grep -o '\w*' find.txt | sort | uniq > find.txt
```

But, when I do the same using the `system` command of perl, I get a blank `find.txt`. Following is my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $conf_file = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/ns.conf";
my $find_file = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find.txt";


system("cat \"$conf_file\" | grep \"add\\|set\\|enable\" | awk '{print \$2}' > /home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find.txt");
system("grep -o \'\\w*\' $find_file | sort | uniq > /home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find.txt");
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Run a `perl` script only to execute `system()` commands has little sense for me. Better way is to use a shell script, but `perl` is powerful enought to do it by itself.

Comment: Why write a Perl wrapper that thin around shell commands?

Comment: find.txt is at the same time input and output file in a pipe. I am surprised that this is working in the shell script, it should not work anywhere.

Comment: `cat` is completely useless in the first command. And I don't see why the output of `awk` isn't simply piped through grep.

Comment: @Birei innaM This is an example code. I need to execute this from perl as the find.txt file needs to be saved in a dynamically created folder. which (the folder) gets deleted after execution of the script. Thats our framework. 
Slaven yes, the .sh file gives the required result.

Comment: Can anyone, simplify this? I just need the find.txt file with the result, in the required folder.

Comment: Or, if I could have the result in an array.

Comment: One simplification: `sort -u`

Comment: But, why is the find.txt blank? While my .sh scripts gets me the result.

Comment: Look. Either this is just an example that is not supposed to work. Or this is supposed to work. Why don't you show us the real code? `find.txt` is blank because of the reason Slaven Rezic gave you an hour ago.

Comment: And what exactly is it that you want to capture with `grep -o '\w*'`?

Comment: @Srittam: If you shell script works, you are getting lucky and winning the race condition between `grep` reading `file.txt` and the shell truncating it via the `>` operator. Use a temp file.

Comment: Why a temporary file when you can take all those pieces and form a single pipe?

Comment: I've edited your question. It's `system`, not `System` (Perl is case-sensitive).

Answer (score 2):

How to do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use charnames qw( :full :short );
use English qw( -no_match_vars ) ;  # Avoids regex performance penalty

my $conf_file = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/ns.conf";
my $find_file = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find.txt";

# cat "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/ns.conf" | grep "add\|set\|enable" | awk '{print $2}' > find.txt
# grep -o '\w*' find.txt | sort | uniq > find.txt

# save unique items
my %list = ();

open my $in_fh, '<', $conf_file or die "could not open $conf_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
while( my $line = <$in_fh> ){

    # grep "add\|set\|enable"
    if( $line =~ m{ add\|set\|enable }msx ){

        # awk '{print $2}'
        my @fields = split "\N{SPACE}", $line;
        $list{ $fields[1] } = 1;

    }
}
close $in_fh or die "could not close $conf_file: $OS_ERROR\n";

# output the sorted list
open my $out_fh, '>', $find_file or die "could not open $find_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
for my $item ( sort keys %list ){
  print {$out_fh} "$item\n" or die "could not print to $find_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
}
close $in_fh or die "could not close $find_file: $OS_ERROR\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even going to get into your [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) in your system commands, or the fact you're defining a `$find_file`, yet instead of using the variable in your `system` command, you hard code the file path, or the fact you use `sort | uniq` when you could have used `sort -u`.

My question is why are you bothering with system commands when you can easily do everything, and do it much more efficiently directly in Perl?:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);
use constant {
    FIND_FILE  => '/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find.txt',
    CONF_FILE  => '/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/ns.conf',
};

open my $conf_fh, "<", CONF_FILE;
my %conf_hash;
while ( my $line = <$conf_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    next unless line =~ /add|set|enable\s+(\w+)/;
    $conf_hash{$1} = $1;
}
close $conf_fh;

open my $find_fh, ">", FIND_FILE;
for my $config ( sort keys %conf_hash ) {
    say {$find_fh} $config;
}
close $find_fh;
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for since I don't know the format of `conf.ns`, so my regex match might not be 100% accurate.

Two loops: The first stores whatever you're looking for in a hash as hash keys. This takes care of the *unique* issue (`sort | uniq`). The second merely sorts those stored keys and prints them out.

Simple and clean, and probably much faster too. Plus, I don't spawn and wait for two other processes to complete, and I no longer have a dependency issue on my operating system. Solaris`version of`grep`doesn't have an`-o` parameter<sup>1</sup>, and Windows doesn't have these basic Unix style commands.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least it didn't the last time I worked on Solaris which was quite a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

@Slaven, I piped it to a new file and its working now. Thank you very much. Here is the code:

```
\#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $conf_file = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/ns.conf";
my $find_file = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find.txt";
my $find_file2 = "/home/atsuser/Users/srittamp/find2.txt";

system("cat \"$conf_file\" | grep \"add\\|set\\|enable\" | awk '{print \$2}' >   $find_file");
system("grep -o \'\\w*\' $find_file | sort | uniq > $find_file2");
```

Now find2.txt has the correct result.

I would appreciate if anyone can suggest a simpler way to do this. Asking as I am new to grep/awk/cat etc..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this, without even involving `perl`, since the tools to accomplish what you want already exist (although doing it in `perl` or `python` might be slightly more efficient if your files are really large, it's a bit more work to actually write/test/debug it correctly):

```
awk '/add|set|enable/{print $2}' conf.txt | sort -u > find.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config file:

```
set ns config -IPAddress 10.102.40.17 -netmask 255.255.255.0
enable ns feature WL SP LB CS SSL SSLVPN AppFw
enable ns mode L3 Edge USNIP PMTUD
set system parameter -natPcbForceFlushLimit 4294967295
set system user nsroot 114d02da8ec8def10b3fba5c29dfd9e6343484399ea3f79e3 -encrypted -timeout 0
set rsskeytype -rsstype ASYMMETRIC
set lacp -sysPriority 32768 -mac 00:30:48:b9:76:14
set ns hostName nk11p00it-nsc-ext001a
set interface 0/1 -throughput 0 -bandwidthHigh 0 -bandwidthNormal 0 -intftype "Intel 8247X" -ifnum 0/1
set interface 0/2 -throughput 0 -bandwidthHigh 0 -bandwidthNormal 0 -intftype "Intel 8247X" -ifnum 0/2
set interface 1/1 -throughput 0 -bandwidthHigh 0 -bandwidthNormal 0 -intftype "Intel 8247X" -ifnum 1/1
set interface 1/2 -throughput 0 -bandwidthHigh 0 -bandwidthNormal 0 -intftype "Intel 8247X" -ifnum 1/2
set interface 1/3 -throughput 0 -bandwidthHigh 0 -bandwidthNormal 0 -intftype "Intel 8247X" -ifnum 1/3
set interface 1/4 -throughput 0 -bandwidthHigh 0 -bandwidthNormal 0 -intftype "Intel 8247X" -ifnum 1/4
```

Here, I want to find the 2nd words of the commands where "Add, Set and Enable" are the 1st words.

So, I was searching for Add, Set, Enable lines and then the second word of those lines and at last eliminating the duplicates.

The problem with using the constant is that, the folder where ns.conf and my find.txt are stores is a dynamically generated folder at run time and then gets deleted every time the script run ends.

For example, in my actual script, ns.conf adn find.txt will be stored in the following folder:

```
my $conf_file = "$SUITE_PATH/$test_instance_id/ns.conf";
```

where, $test_instance_id gets created during run time, which is a unique number and also the folder name for that run.